# Grant Permission to Run Process with FIFO

Tags: permissions, scheduling, fifo

I am trying to run a program that sets its own scheduler policy to `sched_FIFO`, but it errors out saying *operation not permitted*. If I run it with `sudo` then it succeeds, but I want to reduce the permissions it has to only what it needs.
How can I get a normal user to be able to run this program that requires permission to set itself to `sched_FIFO`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man capabilities` shows that for system calls like `sched_setscheduler()`
the process needs the `CAP_SYS_NICE` capability. After you have compiled
the program into, say, file `myprogram` you can set this capability with the command:

```
sudo setcap CAP_SYS_NICE+ep myprogram
```

It can then be run without being root.

Comment: `sudo setcap CAP_SYS_NICE+ep myprogram` failed. It said `Failed to set capabilities on file 'myprogram'  (Operation not supported)
The value of the capability argument is not permitted for a file. Or the file is not a regular (non-symlink) file`, where myprogram is the acutal name of the executable. I also tried the full path and relative path. Also, I am currently testing it in an Ubuntu virtual machine on windows...

Comment: It did test ok for me on a "real" Linux. Perhaps your file is not on a filesystem that supports extended attributes ? You may need to mount the disk with option `user_xattr`.

Comment: ok, `sudo setcap CAP_SYS_NICE+ep myprogram` worked in my home directory. How do you mount the disk with that option? I tried adding `-o user_xattr` in my mount command but it said `unknown mount option 'user_xattr'`

Comment: Support for extended attributes depends on the filesystem type. For example, `man ext4` lists it as a mount option. You need to check for your filesystem type.